# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync never return in c# Universal Windows app

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I create a Universal Windows c# projet with Visual Studio 2015

I import the Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 nuget (version 1.9.2.1420)

I add the following code in the empty project :

```
try
            {
            Uri SecretsUri=new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secret.json", UriKind.Absolute);

            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                            SecretsUri,
                            new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
                            "user",
                            CancellationToken.None).Result;

            calservice = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "MyApp",
                });
            return (calservice != null);
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            CustomFunctionToLogException(ex);
            return false;
            }
```

I added the json file containing the client Id / secret (with action build = content)

I checked all the capacities in the Package.appxmanifest

This code is supposed to launch Internet Explorer (or Edge, Chrome,...) for logging to the Google account but nothing happens, the function never returns, no exception is generated.

I have the same result when I debug on my Windows 10 or on my Windows Mobile 10 preview.

I wrote the same program in C# for windows desktop using the same nuget : It works perfectly as expected (except the first parameter of AuthorizeAsynch is different : ClientsSecrets instead of Uri)

As it is the first time I develop Universal Windows App I must have forgot something... But don't know what...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only diff between the code that you have the one that worked for me lately (https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/master/Blogger.Sample/Blogger.Sample.Shared/Repository/BloggerRepository.cs#L40) is that I'm using async-await. 2 things to consider: 1) From which thread are you calling this method? I think it should be form the UI thread. 2) The code was never tested for Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. Code is called from UI thread. I already tried async / await but I get a compilation error : UserCredential doesn't contain a definition for GetAwaiter...

Comment: Why do you use the Result of GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync, can you just await for it? Please attached your updated code, apparently you are misusing async-await and I'll be happy to see that.